# query from InMemory database in .net core unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core, .net-core, in-memory-database

i am using UseInMemoryDatabase() function in below code statement:

```
var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<CRUDContext>()
            .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "DBTest1")
            .Options;

        // Run the test against one instance of the context
        using (var context = new CRUDContext(options))
```

now i want to query on "DBTest1" from SQL Server Object Explorer in VS or query on "DBTest1" from Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

how can i do that?

thanks guys.

Comment: Sounds like you’ve misunderstood what this is for, you won’t use it in SSMS, see [this link](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/dotnetOutdatedHelpsYouKeepYourProjectsUpToDate.aspx)

Comment: thank you dear Matt. I used that in unit testing. i want just access to DBTest and querying on it in debugging mode when created OTA. what you mean? can you explain more?

Comment: If you want to look at data whilst debugging tests you can use your context pretty much as you would when debugging your actual application code. But what I meant was that this in memory database is really just for testing so the best way to use it is to just assert what you expect to see in it add the end of each test. By the way I just realised I put the wrong link in my first comment! Here’s the correct [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/in-memory)

Comment: thank you dear matt. i saw that link before. however our need is to query from OTA created database in SQL Server Object Explorer or in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: No problem, this is only meant to be used for testing so I don’t think it’s possible to access it via SSMS.

Comment: In-Memory database means your data stays in the memory, you will not be able access this memory from another application, period. For your requirements use empty SQL Server database for your tests and which you will be able to access through SSMS. Remember to run tests sequentially and clean up database changes after every test.